# How to run npm script (package.json) written in an external js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json

I know it has been covered in different questions but mine is a bit different:
Sorry in advance if it sounds really noob.

this is the script in package.json:

```
"start": "nodemon ./index.js --exec \"node -r babel-register\"",
```

I replaced that with:

```
"start": "node scripts/start.js",
```

and in start.js, I do:

```
const { execSync } = require('child_process')

execSync('nodemon ../index.js --exec \"node -r babel-register\"')
```

which throws an error:

> /bin/sh: nodemon: command not found

Am I right with "execSync"?

I tried import nodemon in the file but it is obviously not helping.

Comment: Is `nodemon` installed globally or as a project dependency?

Comment: its a project dependency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing should work if `nodemon` is installed globally, i.e. with:

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

But if it's installed as a project dependency, i.e. with:

```
npm install --save-dev nodemon
```

Then you'll need to run it from the directory containing all the locally installed binaries: `node_modules/.bin/`

So something like this should work:

```
execSync('./node_modules/.bin/nodemon ../index.js --exec \"node -r babel-register\"')
```

Comment: Thank you. of course. and { stdio: 'inherit' } as an option to keep output in console